# How can I see or save one tensor at runtime in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a model:

```
def __init__(params):
    seq2seq() {
        outputs, states = rnn.rnn(...)
    } 

def step()
    ...
    session.run(output_feed, input_feed)
```

The model is called by:

```
with tf.Session as sess:
    model = create_model(sess) (does __init__, loads checkpoint)
    inputs = ...
    outputs = model.step(sess, inputs)
```

How can I print/save/see what the "states" are, returned by rnn.rnn()?

I have tried tf.Print(states[-1], [states[-1]])  which gives me the shape of the tensor.

```
Tensor("model/seq2seq/Print:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(4096)]), dtype=float32)
```

I have tried states[-1].eval() which provides a series of errors such as:

```
  Compute status: Invalid argument: 
  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder1' with dtype int32
```

I have also tried adding the var to the model to return it, but that did not work:

```
 def __init__():
     ...
     self.state = state 

 def step():
     output_feed.append(self.state)
     result = session.run(output_feed, input_feed)
     return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the value of a tensor in the eval method you can't have a dependency on any placeholders in the graph. In this case the error message tells you that `states[-1]` is dependent on `'encoder1'`.

You can call seesion.run and feed in the value of the placeholder like so:

```
session.run(states[-1], feed_dict={encoder1:[#values for encoder1 here
                                            ]})
```

Where `encoder1` is the placeholder object. This should return you the value of `states[-1]` which you can then serialize to save.

In your specific case `encoder1` may be an internal placeholder within the `rnn` so you might want to run something like:

```
_, state_values = session.run([output_feed, states[-1]], input_feed)
```

To get the value of the variable in the context that your running it.

Comment: The list of invalid arguments is ~40 items long and I'm not sure what "encoder1" refers to just by the stack trace.

Comment: Did you run it before the last edit I did? there are only 2 args(3 including self) in the sample presented?

Comment: The session.run() line throws the error: TypeError: Fetch argument [tensor, tensor, tensor....] has invalid type 'list], can not convert list into tensor

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked after some trial and error!

Comment: Cool, glad to help :) does any edit need to be made to my sample?

Comment: I ended up removing some items from the output_feed, to only include the states[-1] and then did: session.run(...) ,  s = self.state